# cookie timeout is not redirecting to login page when using ajax in asp.net core 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm developing an asp.net core 2.2 SPA and I'm using asp.net core Identity. I've configured the cookie options to redirect to login page:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                .AddErrorDescriber<IdentityErrorMessageDescriber>();

        services.AddAuthentication();
        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Identity/Account/Login");
            options.ReturnUrlParameter = "";
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Identity/Account/AccessDenied");
            options.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Identity/Account/Logout");
            options.SlidingExpiration = false;
        });

        services.AddResponseCaching();
        services.AddMvc(options =>
                {
                    options.CacheProfiles.Add("DefaultNoCache",
                                                new CacheProfile()
                                                {
                                                    Duration = 0,
                                                    Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None,
                                                    NoStore = true
                                                }
                    );

                    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                                        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                                        .Build();
                    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
                })
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddViewLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver())
                .AddFluentValidation(options => {
                    options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>();
                    options.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<SharedLocalizer>();
                });
    }
```

I added the [Authorize] at the top of the controller classes, and I'm using many calls to actions by using JQuery ajax, however when the site expire (timeout) according to ExpireTimeSpan, the actions return 401 http response code to ajax but **never a redirecting to login page is taken place**. Only when I refresh the page, the site redirects to login page.

Another question: Is there a way I can check timeout in client-side since I use Jquery ajax a lot?

Thanks

Comment: 1.You miss adding `services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddDefaultUI(UIFramework.Bootstrap4)`.2.I could not reproduce your issue.How did you use ajax?could you share more details?

Comment: I'm not using DefaultUI since I'm implementing my own login. On the other hand, I'm using jquery, but is a question, My goal is to achieve when user doesn't interact with the SPA for a specific time, it be redirected to the login page.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I have the same problem -- not using Identity, but with my own LDAP authentication -- & have many actions invoked via unobtrusive ajax, and I need a way to log the user back in.